# Tuple<int, int> versus int[2] memory usage

Tags: .net

Does anybody know the memory difference between these two? Or how one would figure it out easily themselves?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a 32-bit CLR, both will have 4 bytes for the lock, 4 bytes for the type handle, and 8 bytes for the two ints. The array, however, will have an extra 4 bytes to store the length (2 in this case), so the array will have 4 bytes overhead.

Sizes (determined by profiling) on 32-bit:
`Tuple<int, int>`: 16 bytes
`int[2]`: 20 bytes
`int[1 to 2]`*: 28 bytes
`int[2, 1]`: 36 bytes
On a 64-bit CLR:
`Tuple<int, int>`: 24 bytes
`int[2]`: 32 bytes
`int[1 to 2]`*: 40 bytes
`int[2, 1]`: 48 bytes

Note that single-dimensional zero-based arrays of value types are the smallest possible arrays. Using reference types adds another 4 bytes for the type of object being stored (8 bytes on 64-bit). Using non-zero array bases or multiple dimensions makes it use another kind of array type that stores the rank and lower-bound information, adding 8 additional bytes per dimension.

References:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/arrays.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/net_type_internals.aspx?fid=459323&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2567811
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx

* You can't declare an array with a non-0 lower bound in C#, so I made up the syntax `int[1 to 2]`. You can, however call `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new[]{2}, new[]{10});` to create an array with 2 elements, at index 10 and 11. Of course since such arrays cannot be represented directly in C#'s type system, they aren't terribly useful, but they provide an interesting data point.

Comment: Arrays are a special case, even the IL-optimized ones, and so they have additional overhead in the CLI itself.

Answer (score 0):

A `Tuple<int, int>` uses the same memory as class with two integer fields.  An array on the other hand, has a fairly large internal data structure (called `ArrayOpScript` in the [SSCLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Source_Common_Language_Infrastructure)) that is at least 32-bytes plus another data structure (called `ArrayOpIndexSpec`) for each rank (in this case one) of size 16 bytes.  So an array almost certainly uses several factors more memory than a `Tuple`.

Comment: My profiling on the .Net 4 CLR shows that even a multidimensional array is only 20 or 24 bytes larger than a 2-int class.

Comment: I should have just measured it first instead of trying to reason and speculate.  My measurements show in .NET4 x86 CLR an int[2] consumes only ~20% more memory than a Tuple<int,int>, consistent with your answer.